# how to create a video.js playlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, video.js

is there a way to create a playlist with video.js? at the moment i'm using a webm video as background, and the thing i want to achive is to add another video playing after the first ended. the best result would be to make them playing in a infinite loop.

this is the video tag i have now:

```
<video id="video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
autoplay preload muted width="1080" height="568"
<source src="wp-content/themes/myTheme/video/video1.webm" type='video/webm'/>
</video>
```

an this is the video i want to play after the first one:

```
<video id="video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
autoplay preload muted width="1080" height="568"
<source src="wp-content/themes/myTheme/video/video2.webm" type='video/webm'/>
</video>
```

Comment: tryed nothing yet. i used bigvideo.js before and made it work reading the documentation, but here with video.js i found nothing about it, so since i'm really newb with javascript, i asked here :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar to this. This will listen to the `end` event of the first video, and change the `src` and play the second video.

```js
// Check whether the video has ended, and if so change the src to the next one.
$('video').on('ended', function() {
  $('video source').attr('src', "wp-content/themes/myTheme/video/video2.webm");
  $("video")[0].load();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" autoplay preload muted width="600" height="300"> <source src="wp-content/themes/myTheme/video/video1.webm" type='video/webm' />
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been asked a long time ago, I hope this helps someone
all you need to  do is the following

```
                videojs('my-video').on('ended', function() {

                      var player = videojs('my-video'); //could replace with "this" but just so it is clear to everyone
                      player.pause();
                      var new_url = "newideourl"
                      player.src(new_url);
                      player.load();
                      player.play();

                    });
```